# Android 6.0.1 disable system wide touch input with background service

Tags: java, android

I am an iOS / .Net developer, and this is my first application for Android. I have the necessity to build it because of my child. He uses the phone until late in the night, when he should be asleep because of the school next day.

I found a free on PlayStore, but he was able to bypass it within 3 days, so I tought that I'll build one, and this time unexploitable. Tried also to block his MAC on the router's firewall... but he's got 4G.

The background process is not a problem, already built it, and with a bit of more work it'll be really unkillable (I think). I also have the possibility of root access and install the app as system app.

Is there a way to interact with the UI from a background Service and display an empty activity that catches all touch/physical button events, or even disable completely the input? The phone is Galaxy Note 4 with Android 6.0.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boradcast receiver to update UI from service.